# jQuery animate <object> tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have an `<object>` with an `id` of 'objectID'.

I can modify its position with `.css`:

```
$('#objectID').css({'top': "+=200px"});
```

But when I use `.animate` it won't work:

```
$('#objectID').animate({'top': "+=100px"}, 1000);
```

or

```
$('#objectID').animate({top: "10"}, slow);
```

Or any other variation, which works on divs. Is there a limitation to animating `object` elements?

Comment: You seem to be right, whatever I do I can't get the object tag to animate: http://jsfiddle.net/bw9Kb/9/

Comment: Shorthand animations such as `slideDown()` and `fadeOut()` also have no effect, so it's not your syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to avoid using an <iframe> tag, so I used the <object>, so that I can put in independent stuff inside. But I guess I'll have fall into the pit of memory bloats that is IFRAME!

Comment: I've posted a hack that you can use instead. I wouldn't want you to resort to iframes!

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `<object>` tag is not supported you can hack out your own animation like this:

```
var obj = $('#objectID');
var speed = 50;
var distance = 100;

var i = setInterval(function() {
    obj.css({'top': '+=1px' });
    if (parseInt(obj.css('top')) > distance) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, speed);
```

Change the speed variable to get the animation speed you need.

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw9Kb/25/).

Comment: Seems like a nice workaround, however, with a <div> tag around it, the .animate does work, so I'd prefer that...

Answer (score 0):

In order to animate with top your element needs position, eg position:relative or position:absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the appropriate css for this object?

```
​#objectID{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  ...
}​
```

Indeed I believe `Object` may not be supported for `animate()`. I was able to use `.css` in a jsfiddle.

Should be able to use `.css()` though:
http://jsfiddle.net/mkprogramming/bw9Kb/15/

Comment: In OP's defence. It doesn't work when attempted properly: http://jsfiddle.net/bw9Kb/9/

Comment: Indeed, so I'm guessing the <object> element is not properly supported for the .animate function (yet).

Comment: @Gasman That looks like the answer. No support for that element.

Comment: You are able to use .css though

Answer (score 0):

`$('#objectID').animate({'top': "+=100px"}, 1000);`
The quotes are not needed around `top`.

`$('#objectID').animate({top: "10"}, slow);` 
The integer should not be surrounded by quotes and `slow` should be surrounded by quotes.

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I am assuming you have the appropriate CSS since you can change the position via `.css()`

Comment: Did you actually try this? Because it makes no difference.