# jQuery animation() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Sorry but I just can't for the world understand why it isn't working. Been testing different things the whole day. I suspected my different jQuery sources but testing in jSFiddle gives me the same result. This should be an easy fix. I just want an animation when clicking on one of the circles to bring up a submenu from the right side of the screen.

The Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YWTt2/14/

The html part is mainly SVG stuff so there's noting to see, below is the JavaScript part and it's all in the jsfiddle.

```
//Function for opening submenus and animation
    $(document).on("click", "a[name='menu1']", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#menu1").css({visibility:"visible"});
        $("#menu1").animate({left:'550px'});
    //$("#menu1").slideDown(5110);
    });

      $(document).on("click", "a[name='menu2']", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#menu2").css({visibility:"visible"});
    });

    $(document).on("click", "a[name='menu3']", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#menu3").css({visibility:"visible"});
    });
    $(document).on("click", "a[name='menu4']", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#menu4").css({visibility:"visible"});
    });
     $(document).on("click", "a[name='menu5']", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#menu5").css({visibility:"visible"});
    });


     //Closes the open submenus
     $("#controlnav").on("click", function (e) {
    $("#menu1,#menu2,#menu3,#menu4,#menu5").css({visibility:"hidden"});
    });
```

Comment: You have no elements with the id of menu1 (`#menu1`), so that's a good start.  Maybe you intend `a[name='menu1']` as your selector instead.  My suggestion: delete this question, fix your selectors, and if it still doesn't work, ask again.

Comment: You must have missed it its on line 193 on the html: <object id="menu1">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, You just need to update the `jQuery` file to the latest one (jQuery 2.x).

check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pragneshok/YWTt2/15/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the  tag. Is not supported.

Check out this answer: [jQuery animate <object> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398888/jquery-animate-object-tag)

Comment: Ok, so if I use and older jQuery version I should do a workaround of some, maybe a <div>. But as of jQuery version 2.x onvards it seems to work on the <object>.... Edit: Tested using a div around an object using jQuery 1.11 but didn't work.